# create custom post type for category

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

How can I create a custom post type for a category  like this sample.That I will input the text in the input box and fetch it as a category name.

```
public function panotour_register_post_type(){
    register_post_type(self::$custom_post_type,array(
            'taxonomies' => array('category'),
            'name'         => 'CategoryName',
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'query_var' => true
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: Did you mean **Convert Custom Taxonomy to Custom Post Type** ?

Answer (score 0):

create a custom post type and add that post type to a category using taxonomies,

```
function create_post_type() {
    $args = array(
        'label'               => __( 'cpost', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'description'         => __( 'Custom Post Type', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'revisions', 'custom-fields', ),
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'menu_position'       => 5,
        'can_export'          => true,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'capability_type'     => 'page',
        'taxonomies'          => array( 'category_name' ),
    );

    // Registering  Custom Post Type
    register_post_type('cpost', $args );

}

add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type', 0 );
```

Comment: Thank you very much php user this is great and perfect but what i want is only the name to be put as a category name. For example I will input school,apartment,mall then this things will become a category for the post.Is this possible?